# Returning from Functions C++

Tags: c++, function, return

What I am doing is, I am trying to make a text-based quiz and I want when it goes Game Over, the player has the option to Quit the Quiz or Restart from the beginning, but it would be ask inside a function. I am unable to provide the code here since it's over hundreds of lines, So basically what I want to do is to be able to exit the program or restart it by returning to the top of the int main but the option to do this would be inside a function.

For instance:

```
void Answer
{
Enter 1 to exit and enter to 2 restart
//player inputs number and there is an if else statement
if number == 1
    {
    return (0);
    }
else if number == 2
    {
    return main();
}
int main()
{
question
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: you could use a loop (And don't call into main directly).

Comment: Have two functions: The first runs the game (calls the second function) in a loop and provides the possibility to exit the game.
Note: You can not call main directly!

Comment: You should read a basic guide on C++. It would answer your question for you.

Comment: Also, **StackOverflow is _not_ a coding service.**

Comment: I'll try out the loop method then.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use a while loop and not use a function.

```
int restart(0);

while(restart==1)
{
  // do your quizz

  cout << "Press 1 to restart, 2 to stop" << endl;
  cin << restart;

  // Some test to see if the right thing was put in the restart variable    
}
```

Would not that work ?

Sorry if i misunderstood the question..

Answer (score -1):

The only way to do what you want to do is using C++'s exception (`throw` and `catch`) mechanism.

In C one can use `setjmp` and longjmp` but with less safety.

Generally this is considered to be a good idea only for error handling or other exceptional reasons and not for normal operation.

For normal operation one should rather allow the function stack to unroll normally by returning until one is back in main.

Comment: He could also use `goto` :) (I'm just kidding, don't do that!)

Comment: It's by far not the **only** way to do this.

Comment: Yeah, I just found out recently that goto is not supposed to be used anymore. @doron I just started programming like 1 and a half month ago so I still don't know how to use the exception mechanism.

Comment: goto cannot jump out of functions.